# How to move a rectangle that's used as a Meter bar in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a vertical meter for values between 2 ranges.

so what i tried so far, was to make a frame, and under it put a mask, and under that a rectangle.
with the idea, of lowering/increasing the rectangle Y position to make it seems to move.

```
rect.position = new Vector3(rect.position.x, (rect.position.y - rect.sizeDelta.y));
```

so i did that, to first lower by it's height, so the bar will seem empty.
but it doesn't work right, the position depends on the screen size, and the rect Y end up way lower then exactly his height.

so, tl;dr, i want a bar that i can give a value between 0-100 and it will fill it according to that.
and i might have gone wrong about it.

so, any suggestions would be appreciated.

**edit**:
Add picture to show what i want the bar to look like:

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want - could you provide an illustration?

Comment: i've add a picture of what i want to have, i very new to unity, so it might be something trivial, but i'm facing a brick wall.
maybe there is a better way to implement such a thing

Comment: Is this something that will be used for GUI? If so, consider looking into that: http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i feel kinda dumb
I didn't realize how customizable the **Slider** control is.

I removed it's handle, unchecked interactble and removed it's background, and now i can give it a value between 0-100 and it works exactly as i wanted.

thanks Mathias Siig Nørregaard for referencing me to the video link that opened my eyes.